# JSON PHP array decode - Access specific data

Tags: php, json, decode

I can't find out how to echo "tags" in this JSON data.

```
{"totalHits":26,"hits":[{"previewHeight":92,"tags":"sunflower, sunflower field, flora"}]};
```

I can echo "totalHits", by using this:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->totalHits; // 26
```

Comment: first use var_dump($obj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using **`print_r`** to make it easier for you to trace the array

The output of `print_r($obj);`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [totalHits] => 26
    [hits] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [previewHeight] => 92
                    [tags] => sunflower, sunflower field, flora
                )

        )

)
```

So your object can be accessed like this

```
echo $obj->hits[0]->tags;
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your JSON in a readable format

```
{
    "totalHits": 26,
    "hits": [{
        "previewHeight": 92,
        "tags": "sunflower, sunflower field, flora"
    }]
};
```

we can see that `tags` is a property of the `hit` object

and `$obj->hits` is an array containing `hit` objects

so...

```
echo $obj->hits[0]->tags;
```